# Slow parsing of mutiple XML files to CSV

Tags: python, xml, pandas

The code below is written as part of a parser, which files would be also added here: [XMLParser](https://controlc.com/278cba81), [parser](https://controlc.com/99f38ba3), [Name](https://controlc.com/946ee090), [GenericElement](https://controlc.com/6f80dc30), [attrib](https://controlc.com/94586504)

It reads an XML files from a folder, turn them into a dataframe using pandas and then parse it into a CSV file.

```
from generic_parser import XMLParser
import pandas as pd
import os

opdatas = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
tags_to_leave = ['Description', 'FileX', 'FileY']
value_data = ['SetData']

def dropper(obj):
    return obj.name not in tags_to_leave + value_data, True

def opdata_collector(obj):
    cnt = 0
    global df
    if obj.name == 'START':
        obj.recurs_drop(dropper)
        obj.recurs_change(rename_attribs)
        obj = rename_attribs(obj)
        # opdatas.append(obj)
        final_dict = dict(obj.attribs)
        # final_dict.update({'ValueData' : []})
        value_data_dict = {}
        for child in obj.children:
            if str(child.name) in tags_to_leave:
                final_dict.update(dict(child.attribs))
            if str(child.name) in value_data:
                for key_name in child.attribs.keys():
                    print(key_name)
                    final_dict['SetData' + key_name + str(cnt)] = child.attribs[key_name]
                cnt += 1

        df = df.append(final_dict, ignore_index=True)

def rename_attribs(obj):
    if str(obj.name) == 'Description':
        obj.attribs["text"] = obj.text
    obj.attribs.sub_keys(r"^(.*)$", str(obj.name) + r"_\1")
    return obj



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #xml = XMLParser.parse(r'./work.xml')
    #xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
    #df.to_csv("./original.csv")
    directory= 'C:/Users/232/Desktop/32/Files/test'
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            xml.recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
            df.to_csv("./output.csv")
            continue
        else:
            continue
```

This is the XML file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectData>
<FINAL>
    <START id="DG0003" service_code="0x517B">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>23423</Rational>
        <Qualify>342342</Qualify>
      </Docs>
      <Description num="3423423f3423">The third</Description>
      <SetFile dg="" dg_id="">
        <FileX dg="" axis_pts="2" name="" num="" dg_id="" />
        <FileY tint="" axis_pts="20" name="TOOLS" num="23423" tint_id="" />
        <SetData x="E1" value="21259" />
        <SetData x="E2" value="0" />
      </SetFile>
    </START>
    <START id="ID0048" service_code="0x5198">
      <Docs Docs_type="START">
        <Rational>225198</Rational>
        <Quality >343243324234234</Quality >
      </Docs>
      <Description num="434234234">The forth</Description>
      <Normal tint="m" tint_id="FEDS">
        <FileX be="dssad" get="false" axis_pts="19" name="asdas" num="SDF3" tint_id="SDGFDS" />
        <SetData xin="sdf" xax="233" value="323" />
        <SetData xin="123" xax="213" value="232" />
        <SetData xin="2321" xax="232" value="23" />
        <SetData xin="-inf" xax="45" value="423" />
        <SetData xin="234" xax="3" value="4523" />
        <SetData xin="324" xax="423" value="6456234" />
        <SetData xin="30" xax="45234" value="34532" />
        <SetData xin="5345" xax="2345" value="453" />
        <SetData xin="234" xax="345" value="4543" />
        <SetData xin="2321" xax="2345" value="45" />
        <SetData xin="3423432" xax="34" value="453" />
        <SetData xin="21" xax="34" value="45" />
        <SetData xin="12" xax="34" value="345" />
        <SetData xin="43" xax="423" value="7" />
        <SetData xin="64" xax="32" value="0" />
        <SetData xin="434" xax="254" value="5" />
        <SetData xin="343" xax="322" value="3" />
        <SetData xin="36" xax="2" value="0" />
        <SetData xin="23" xax="done" value="0" />
      </Normal>
    </START>
</FINAL>
</ProjectData>
```

The code works fine however the speed is not optimal. It takes quite some time to parse multiple XML files into one CSV.

The screenshot below shows the output file (I just removed the data for personal reasons). The columns show how the data is distributed

[image]

Comment: Looks like your story https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269185/order-of-xml-to-csv-not-right relied on `if obj.name == 'START'`, not on `if obj.name == 'OPDATA'` as well as your xml content points to that. Would you update the code?

Comment: I fixed the xml file now. Today I  tried the code with  around 5 xml files that have same structure and it took a long time until it got parsed into a csv file

Comment: Could you provide a broad overview of your program? GenericElement mentions something about EXAM, is that relevant/important here? My first thought when I hear _XML_ and _speed is not optimal_ is "lxml".

Comment: Your `tags_to_leave` list doesn't refer to anything that's in the xml you've included. Can you also give a small sample csv output?

Comment: And there is still no `"OPDATA"` in the XML file, so your parsing will do nothing. Also, you are always adding to the global `df`, which means that each written CSV contains the content of all parsed XML files that came before, not just the one you are currently parsing. No wonder this is slow.

Comment: @Graipher It should be start, so in my laptop the code work I fixed the code here also. what would you recommend  doing to make it faster ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to extract from the XML, maybe with some example input -> output?

Comment: Did you forget `xml = XMLParser.parse(filename)` in your example for loop?

Comment: @09_Conflict, I copied the code right, the code works fine as said before it just take quite some time when it comes to reading multiple xmls and parsing them to a single csv

Answer (score 4):

An easy speed-up is not using a global object that you continually modify. This is especially important since you also save the output file over and over, which is completely unnecessary (unless you care about the current state if you abort the program).

```
from itertools import chain
from pathlib import Path
...

def opdata_collector(obj):
    if obj.name != 'START':
        return {}
    count = 0
    obj.recurs_drop(dropper)
    obj.recurs_change(rename_attribs)
    obj = rename_attribs(obj)
    final_dict = dict(obj.attribs)
    for child in obj.children:
        if str(child.name) in tags_to_leave:
            final_dict.update(dict(child.attribs))
        elif str(child.name) in value_data:
            final_dict.update({f"ValueData{key_name}{count}": value
                               for key_name, value in child.attribs.items()})
            count += 1
    return final_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    directory = Path('C:/Users/z647818/Desktop/Erdi/Files/test')
    data = (XMLParser.parse(directory / file_name).recurs_collect(opdata_collector)
            for file_name in os.listdir(directory)
            if file_name.endswith(".xml"))
    df = pd.DataFrame(chain.from_iterable(data))
    df.dropna().to_csv("./output.csv")
```

On top of that the actual `opdata_collector` can probably also be improved, but this should give you a nice boost.

I also removed unneeded lines, used a dictionary comprehension in the inner loop, turned the `if` into an `elif` (you probably don't want a tag to be processed twice), spelled out `count` (no need to conserve bytes), used an `f-string` instead of string addition and packed the dataframe generation in one big generator expression.

Comment: thank you a lot for your answer. I added the code of mine and the part from your answer and it can be seen [HERE](https://controlc.com/8c8194ab) but I'm getting _AttributeError: 'Attribs' object has no attribute 'items'_

Comment: @ebe I tried it with the file you gave. I'll check again tomorrow if the latest version still works for me.

Comment: I have updated the data and also have added a screenshot on how the output looks like(I just removed the data for confidential reasons).  It takes a couple of minutes when I run it for 3 xml files. The plan is to use many many more xml and at the current speed of my code it is just not possible.

Comment: would really appreciate it, if you can have a look at the added part in the question and the comment above. Your code as it for not only has given me a column of numbers and nothing else